# MVC3, Entity Framework, OpenID and MembershipProvider

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4, asp.net-membership, openid, membership-provider

I am creating a project that uses EF Code First approach and now I have to create the users. I want to implement OpenID, because it is really cool and modern. There are plenty of tutorials of how to do that (haven't read them, but I will of course).

I am pretty used now to EF and MVC, but all the stuff with the members, roles, providers, etc is foggy. There are two things that I am certain of:

- I want to use OpenID and
- I want to manage the users table with EF Code First

So I would appreciate if anyone can give me some hints:

- Do I have to implement the MembershipProvider or I could use a project like this one: [codeplex](http://efmembership.codeplex.com/)?
- How OpenID, EF and Membership will go along with each other?

I know that this is VERY wide subject, but I need only basic hints, I need to know from where to start. Things like "You can use MembershipProvider and OpenID, but you better don't, because...".

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Look at the http://nerddinner.com tutorial to see how they are using OpenID, code at http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/

Comment: *I want to implement OpenID, because it is really cool and modern.* I can hardly imagine more odd reason to use any technology or approach. Unless you have specific requirement which will be satisfied by some technology or approach you should think twice before using it.

Comment: The requirement is the users to be able to log in with facebook, yahoo and others, as it is very annoying to create accounts everywhere. This will make our website much more social and easy to work with. From user point of perspective this functionality is modern and cool - the fact that you can start doing stuff around without the need to actually go trough the process of registering is important for them. Besides we are not developing a business website or an intranet site which requires proper authentication and authorization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The requirement is the users to be able to log in with facebook, yahoo
>   and others, as it is very annoying to create accounts everywhere.

What we are looking at is providing multiple **Authentication** options to our end **Users**, whether it be a username and password combination that you manage, an OpenId provider or an OAuth provider.

I find the best approach is to make these two concepts (membership and authentication) explicit.

> I don't really care, how the user **authenticates**, just providing I
>   can find their **user** information when they do.

A simple approach to have a User table with the following information:

```
Name
Email
Authentication Type
Authentication Id
```

Example:

```
Name        Email       AuthenticationType      AuthenticationId
----        -------     ------------------      ----------------    
John        a@b.com     GoogleOpenId            OpenIdClaimId
Ben         c@d.com     Internal                ben
Dave        e@f.com     FacebookOAuth           FacebookUserId
```

When the user authenticates, we can load their user information using the authentication method and id as the criteria. For the internal membership provider we can use their username, for OpenId their claim url and for OAuth their provider id (such as the Twitter id).

So by all means use EF to manage your **Users** but I would treat the membership provider as just another authentication mechanism in which case you may as well use the standard SqlMembershipProvider.

I wrote [this post](http://blogs.planetcloud.co.uk/mygreatdiscovery/post/Customers-users-and-logins.aspx) a long time ago (in the context of eCommerce stores) that may be of some use.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. After a lot of searching I found how to and made a custom implementation of the MemebershipProvider. It was not easy but now I am really proud of what I did. The example with the table is very nice and I used a similar approach (as it is the first and may be the best thing that you may come up with). Anyway I will mark your post as answer as it would have been helpful.